# wordpress thumbnail images missing after server change

Tags: php, wordpress, thumbnails

I have recently changed the server that my wordpress site was on. I've also made a change to the URL.

I ran duplicator on the old site, uploaded it on the new site but since the change I've had some weird things happening.

On one of my portfolio pages its showing a load of missing images -
however if I click on them and inspect then it shows the url, which if I visit it, its there fine.
[image: missing images]

I've also got image thumbnails missing in my media library, but when I check - they are there [image: missing thumbnails]

I've installed a thumbnail regenerator which says its finished but nothing has changed.
Any ideas what's happened?
The only thing I can think is that I've gone from php 7.3.28 to 8.0.21 but I cant think that would make some images fail and others ok?

I've deactivated all the plugins and the media was the same so everything is reactivated now.

This is the code from one that is displaying correctly:
`<img width="60" height="60" src="https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/07/website-services-150x150.jpg" class="attachment-60x60 size-60x60" alt="" loading="lazy" srcset="https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/07/website-services-150x150.jpg 150w, https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/07/website-services-300x300.jpg 300w, https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/07/website-services-800x800.jpg 800w, https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/07/website-services-768x768.jpg 768w, https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/07/website-services.jpg 1080w" sizes="(max-width: 60px) 100vw, 60px">`

and this is missing thumbnail
`<img width="60" height="60" src="https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/07/advertising-5-150x150.jpg" class="attachment-60x60 size-60x60" alt="" loading="lazy" srcset="https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/07/advertising-5-150x150.jpg 150w, https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/07/advertising-5-300x300.jpg 300w, https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/07/advertising-5.jpg 500w" sizes="(max-width: 60px) 100vw, 60px">`

So there are a few sizes different but that shouldnt stop the thumbnail showing?

Comment: On the page that has the problems, open your web inspector and look for errors. Don’t click the images because that’s probably a different URL. Most likely it is a wrong URL that is 404’ing

Comment: _"So there are a few sizes different but that shouldnt stop the thumbnail showing?"_ - well if one of those versions gets requested by the browser, that does not actually exist, and dynamic on-the-fly generation then fails ... But how come the sizes have changed at all, when you said you _duplicated_ the site to move it to a different server? Duplicate, by any usual definition, should mean _identical_.

Comment: _"I've installed a thumbnail regenerator which says its finished but nothing has changed."_ - have you checked PHP and server error log afterwards?